# How to change filename before duplicating Applescript

Tags: applescript

Currently I have a Applescript that does the following:

- Copy a file from a certain directory to the current opened finder window.
- Open a dialog box to rename this file.

However, it would be nicer if the dialog box to specify a name pops up *before* the moving takes place, so the original file is not copied first and then renamed. Could anyone help me how to achieve this?

```
property y : POSIX file "/Users/thijmendam/Documents/Newfile/Naamloos.txt" as alias

tell application "Finder"
 set x to target of window 1 as alias
 duplicate y to x
 set name of file "Naamloos.txt" of folder x to the text returned of (display dialog "Rename" default answer "")
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
property y : POSIX file "/Users/thijmendam/Documents/Newfile/Naamloos.txt" as alias

tell application "Finder"
    set x to target of window 1 as alias
    set newFileName to text returned of (display dialog "Rename" default answer "")
    set name of (duplicate y to x with replacing) to newFileName
end tell
```

I added `with replacing` to prevent an error being thrown if a file of that name already exists.  You can remove this or just add a `try...on error...end try` error-catching block to cater for this situation.

The *Terminal* command `cp` can also be used to copy files from the command line.  This will copy the file *myfile.ext* from the Desktop to the Documents folder without renaming it:

```
cp ~/Desktop/myfile.ext ~/Documents/
```

This will copy and rename the file in one go:

```
cp ~/Desktop/myfile.ext ~/Documents/renamed.ext
```

Note that `cp` will overwrite existing files without warning.

You can execute *Terminal* commands directly from within AppleScript using `do shell script`.

Implementing this with the AppleScript above could be done like this:

```
property y : POSIX file "/Users/CK/Desktop/syringet.jpg" as alias

tell application "Finder"
    set x to POSIX path of (target of front window as alias)
    set newFileName to text returned of (display dialog "Rename" default answer "")
    set y to POSIX path of y
end tell

set command to "cp " & quoted form of y & " " & quoted form of ([x, newFileName] as text)
do shell script command
```

On a final note, if you didn't want to have to specify the file's extension in the dialog box (as it's unlikely you'll need to change that), you can make use of the `name extension` property.  In the case of *Naamloos.txt*, the value of this property will be `"txt"`.

Amend the scripts to reflect this implementation:

```
set name of (duplicate y to x with replacing) to newFileName & "." & name extension of y
```

in the first instance, or:

```
        ...
        set [ext, y] to [name extension, POSIX path] of y
end tell

set command to "cp " & quoted form of y & " " & quoted form of ([x, newFileName, ".", ext] as text)
```

Comment: Done the job. Thank you a lot :-)

Comment: You're welcome.  Feel free to +1 and mark the answer as correct.  It helps others and gives me brownie points.

Comment: Also, as an after thought, that script would throw an error if a file of the original name already existed at the destination, i.e. if there were a *Naamloos.txt* in folder `x`.  To avoid or cater for this error, you can use `set name of (move (duplicate y) to x) to newFilename`, which first duplicates the file at its present location, moves it and then renames it.  You'll get hear a double chime from Finder as it performs two file actions, but it deals with filename clashes.

Comment: Thank you again! I gave feedback, but my reputation is not high enough for it to be visible to others.

Comment: Not to worry.  Thank you very much.

Comment: And for anyone else reading this in the future - why didn't I use the terminal command 'touch'? Well, touch works for text based files. However if I execute touch with a file such as .pages, the file is corrupted.

Comment: That's because `touch` is not used to copy files; it's used to "change file access and modification times".  To copy files from *Terminal*, you would use `cp` like this: `cp ~/Desktop/picture.jpg ~/Pictures/renamed_pic.jpg`.